# How to set touch gestures / hammer.js active on a specific viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hammer.js

I've just finished constructing my carousel slider with touch events for a website I'm building. Currently trying to figure out how I can active or disable the touch events`(hammer)` on specific viewports. Basically once it reaches a mobile / tablet viewport. Hammer.js will iniate disabling on-click controls for the slider

```js
var activeSlide = 0;
    $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carousel            = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position            = 0,
            currentSlide        = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            // Decremement current slide
            currentSlide--;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    });
    
    $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // store variable relevent to clicked slider
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize   = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position = 0,
            currentSlide = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
        if (currentSlide < facultyProfileCount - 1) {
            // Increment current slide
            currentSlide++;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    })
    
    
    function touchCarousel() {
        $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').each(function() {
    
            // create a simple instance
            // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
    
            var direction,
                touchSlider = this,
                mc = new Hammer.Manager(this),
                itemLength = $(this).find('li').length,
                count = 0,
                slide = $(this),
                timer;
    
            var sliderWrapper = slide,
                slideItems = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                //slider = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                totalPanels = slideItems.length,
                currentSlide = parseInt(sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
            // mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
            //   direction = ev.type;
            // });
    
            mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({
                threshold: 0,
                pointers: 0
            }));
            
            mc.on('pan', function(e) {
                var percentage = 100 / totalPanels * e.deltaX / window.innerWidth;
                var transformPercentage = percentage - 100 / totalPanels * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + transformPercentage + '% )';
                var sliderWrapper = $(e.target).closest('.faculty-carousel')
    
    
                if (e.isFinal) { // NEW: this only runs on event end
    
                    var newSlide = activeSlide;
                    if (percentage < 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    else if (percentage > 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    goToSlide(newSlide, sliderWrapper);
                }
            });
    
    
            var goToSlide = function(number, sliderWrapper) {
                if (number < 0)
                    activeSlide = 0;
                else if (number > totalPanels - 1)
                    activeSlide = totalPanels - 1
                else
                    activeSlide = number;
    
                sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', activeSlide);
    
                touchSlider.classList.add('slide-animation');
                var percentage = -(100 / totalPanels) * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + percentage + '% )';
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    touchSlider.classList.remove('slide-animation');
                }, 400);
    
            };
        });
    }
    
    
    function panelSizing() {
    
        // var activeSlide = 0;
        // $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
        var viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carouselWrapper = $('.faculty-carousel')
        ;
        
        //Set Panel Size based on viewport
    
        if (viewPortSize <= 1920 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 5
        }
    
    
        if (viewPortSize < 1024 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 4
        }
    
        if (viewPortSize < 768 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 3
        } 
    
        if (viewPortSize < 480 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize
        }
        
        carouselWrapper.each(function(){
            var wrapper = $(this);
            // wrapper.attr('data-slide', '0');
    
            var facultyPanel = wrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            profileCount = facultyPanel.length,
            // activeSlide         = 0,
            carousel            = wrapper.find('.faculty-items');
    
            carousel.outerWidth( profilePanelSize * profileCount );
            facultyPanel.outerWidth(profilePanelSize);
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        });
    }
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
            $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        })
    });
    
    $('.slider-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
    
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline; }
    
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
      display: block; }
    
    body {
      line-height: 1; }
    
    ol, ul {
      list-style: none; }
    
    blockquote, q {
      quotes: none; }
    
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
      content: '';
      content: none; }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; }
    
    .faculty-items.tile-view {
      display: flex !important;
      flex-wrap: wrap !important;
      width: 100% !important; }
    
    .faculty-items li {
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; }
      .faculty-items li > a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        user-drag: none;
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: grey; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(even), .faculty-items a:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: aqua; }
    
    .faculty-items {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear; }
    
    .faculty-carousel .controls {
      display: block; }
    
    /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
    
    

    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You either forgot to ask a question or you simply wanted to announce on [SO] what you are currently trying to figure out. Which one is it? Please read [ask] and make your example a [mcve]. Minimal, in this context, means: *remove all code unnecessary for reproducing your issue*.

Answer (score 0):

Add an identifier (class for example `class="hammerOn"`) to your div.
Bind your hammerjs script to this identifier.
Check the current size of the window with the window resize function.
If the window size reaches the size you do not want hammerjs to be enabled on, remove the class.

Basic idea:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   if (($(window).width() < yourprefwidth) && ($(window).height() < yourprefheight)) {
       $('#yourdiv').removeClass('hammerOn');
   } else {
       $('#yourdiv').addClass('hammerOn');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use css for this,

adding some properties that prevent the user click, check the snippet below:

```js
var activeSlide = 0;
    $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carousel            = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position            = 0,
            currentSlide        = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            // Decremement current slide
            currentSlide--;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    });
    
    $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // store variable relevent to clicked slider
    
        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize   = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position = 0,
            currentSlide = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
        // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
        if (currentSlide < facultyProfileCount - 1) {
            // Increment current slide
            currentSlide++;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');
    
            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }
    })
    
    
    function touchCarousel() {
        $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').each(function() {
    
            // create a simple instance
            // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
    
            var direction,
                touchSlider = this,
                mc = new Hammer.Manager(this),
                itemLength = $(this).find('li').length,
                count = 0,
                slide = $(this),
                timer;
    
            var sliderWrapper = slide,
                slideItems = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                //slider = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
                totalPanels = slideItems.length,
                currentSlide = parseInt(sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide'));
    
            // mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
            //   direction = ev.type;
            // });
    
            mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({
                threshold: 0,
                pointers: 0
            }));
            
            mc.on('pan', function(e) {
                var percentage = 100 / totalPanels * e.deltaX / window.innerWidth;
                var transformPercentage = percentage - 100 / totalPanels * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + transformPercentage + '% )';
                var sliderWrapper = $(e.target).closest('.faculty-carousel')
    
    
                if (e.isFinal) { // NEW: this only runs on event end
    
                    var newSlide = activeSlide;
                    if (percentage < 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                    else if (percentage > 0)
                        newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                    goToSlide(newSlide, sliderWrapper);
                }
            });
    
    
            var goToSlide = function(number, sliderWrapper) {
                if (number < 0)
                    activeSlide = 0;
                else if (number > totalPanels - 1)
                    activeSlide = totalPanels - 1
                else
                    activeSlide = number;
    
                sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', activeSlide);
    
                touchSlider.classList.add('slide-animation');
                var percentage = -(100 / totalPanels) * activeSlide;
                touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + percentage + '% )';
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    touchSlider.classList.remove('slide-animation');
                }, 400);
    
            };
        });
    }
    
    
    function panelSizing() {
    
        // var activeSlide = 0;
        // $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');
    
    
        var viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carouselWrapper = $('.faculty-carousel')
        ;
        
        //Set Panel Size based on viewport
    
        if (viewPortSize <= 1920 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 5
        }
    
    
        if (viewPortSize < 1024 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 4
        }
    
        if (viewPortSize < 768 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 3
        } 
    
        if (viewPortSize < 480 ) {
            var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize
        }
        
        carouselWrapper.each(function(){
            var wrapper = $(this);
            // wrapper.attr('data-slide', '0');
    
            var facultyPanel = wrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            profileCount = facultyPanel.length,
            // activeSlide         = 0,
            carousel            = wrapper.find('.faculty-items');
    
            carousel.outerWidth( profilePanelSize * profileCount );
            facultyPanel.outerWidth(profilePanelSize);
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        });
    }
    
    $('.tile-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('tile-view');
            $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');
        })
    });
    
    $('.slider-layout').on('click', function() {
        $('.faculty-items').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('tile-view');
        })
    })
    
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
    
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        panelSizing();
        touchCarousel()
    
    })
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      font-size: 100%;
      font: inherit;
      vertical-align: baseline; }
    
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
      display: block; }
    
    body {
      line-height: 1; }
    
    ol, ul {
      list-style: none; }
    
    blockquote, q {
      quotes: none; }
    
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
      content: '';
      content: none; }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0; }
    
    .faculty-items.tile-view {
      display: flex !important;
      flex-wrap: wrap !important;
      width: 100% !important; }
    
    .faculty-items li {
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative; }
      .faculty-items li > a {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        user-drag: none;
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: grey; }
    
    .faculty-items li:nth-child(even), .faculty-items a:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: aqua; }
    
    .faculty-items {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear; }
    
    .faculty-carousel .controls {
      display: block; }
    
    /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */

/* BELOW PROPERTIES WILL PREVENT USER TOCH AND THE BUTTONS TO BE CLICKED OR TOCHED AT SPECIFIC VIEWPORT */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .faculty-items {
      user-select: none;
      pointer-events: none;
     }
     .faculty-carousel .controls {
      user-select: none;
      pointer-events: none;
     }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
    
    

    
    <div class="faculty-carousel">
        <ul class="faculty-items">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="prev">
            prev
            </div>
    
            <div class="next">
            next
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```